# Port forward to LocalStack sqs doesn't work

Tags: amazon-sqs, localstack

I'm trying to work with LocalStack sqs queue on docker.
The docker name is awslocal.
I've done port forward on awslocal:4566 -> localhost:9009

From my local service I try to connect to that queue by configuring sqs endpoint: https://localhost:9009

When trying to connect I receive an error:
*Unable to execute HTTP request: awslocal*

Any ideas?